# Не работает Wake On Lan через Teamviewer

Tags: lan, teamviewer

Всем привет. Подскажите с такой проблемой. Хочу будить ноут дома через TeamViewer, в нем есть такая функция. Настроил в BIOS и в ос (windows 10) дома в нутри сети пробуждение работает, а вот из вне не получается. В чем может быть проблема? На роутере открыт порт udp 9.

Comment: Разве wake-on-lan это не arp?

Comment: да. но почему то из внешки не получается. хотя у тимвивера есть опция пробуждения.

Comment: arp не работает вне сети

Comment: и как быть в такой ситуации. По логике тимвивера поулчается я могу это делать только внутри сети?

Comment: @JamesMaynard WOL при пробросе портов не использует TeamViewer.

Comment: по идее я же могу из любой программы отправить на этот порт WOL пакет и он должен включить пк. Я пробую но комп не включается.

Comment: Там речь совершенно про другое идёт. Как я понял, предлагается обойтись без проброса портов и гемора с серым айпи, оставив внутри локальной сети любой (желательно не яблочный) старый смарт и крутить на нём тимвьювер или энидескск. Дале так: ты находясь за пределами этой сети, со своего нового планшета, смарта, компа, тостера открываешь teamviewer/anydesk видишь что твой комп спит, но его можно разбудить отправив пакет внутри сети с того самого старого тапка. Вот только не работает это нихрена. Особенно с вайфай.
Я пытаюсь старый ipad2 приладить, но не могу найти как к нему удалённо подключить

Comment: нужно постоянное устройство с тв в сети, что полный бред. я реализовал это через роутер. когда надо вкл комп я захожу на роутер и там клацаю разбудить. я надеялся что ТВ через свои сервера как то может отправить пакет. но увы не может.

Answer (score 2):

Из [инструкции](https://www.teamviewer.com/ru/res/pdf/TeamViewer-Manual-Wake-on-LAN-ru.pdf) к Teamviewer:

> 5.3 Wake-on-LAN через публичный адрес
>
> Если вы хотите пробудить компьютер с помощью его публичного адреса, ваш компьютер должен быть
>   всё время идентифицирован в Интернете. Для этого нужно либо иметь
>   постоянный IP адрес интернет-провайдера, либо ваш компьютер должен
>   быть доступен, к примеру, с помощью динамического провайдера DNS (см.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS). При выполнении одного из
>   условий, вы можете активировать Wake-On-LAN через публичный адрес в
>   опциях TeamViewer.
>
> Для активации TeamViewer Wake-On-LAN через публичный адрес выполните
>   следующие действия:
>
> 1. Запустите TeamViewer на компьютере.
> 2. В главном меню выберите Дополнительно | Опции.
>      -> Откроется диалоговое окно Опции TeamViewer.
> 3. Выберите раздел Основное.
> 4. В разделе Настройки сети|Функция пробуждения по сети Wake-on-LAN нажмите кнопку Конфигурация….
> 5. Откроется диалоговое окно Функция пробуждения по сети Wake-on-LAN. Нажмите кнопку-переключатель Публичный адрес.
> 6. В поле Адрес введите фиксированный IP адрес или DNS имя компьютера.
> 7. В поле Порт введите порт UDP, с помощью которого организуется доступ к компьютеру (см. Раздел 7.1, стр. 14).
> 8. Нажмите кнопку ОК.
> 9. Теперь компьютер может быть пробуждён через свой публичный адрес с помощью TeamViewer.

Скажите, что из этого вы сделали? Или у вас какая-то другая схема подключения?

Comment: так и сделал. пробовал использовать прямой IP и пробовал днс имя. Не работает. До меня инет доходит от шлюза провайдера (микротик), а потом в мой роутер. Я вот думаю а не может ли микротик провайдера блочить? Вижу что порт открыт.

Comment: @JamesMaynard Вы проброс портов Сделали?

Comment: да конечно. как описал вышел извне проверяю и вижу что порт открыт.

Comment: @JamesMaynard Отвечать нужно с упоминанием пользователя чтобы ему пришло уведомление.

Comment: @JamesMaynard выложите скриншот с настройкой проброса портов.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ с сайта [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_10-power/wake-on-lan-%D0%BD%D0%B5/42096662-7486-4182-bb03-cdab5c044a2c)

У кого сетевые карты на контроллере Realtek- скачивайте драйвер с сайта (Win8, Win8.1 and Server 2012 Auto Installation Program (SID:1726143)). После установки драйвера  WOL заработает. Тот который от Microsoft- не работает. Realtek

Данная проблема встречается только в Windows 10.

Comment: Написано, что WOL Работает в локальной сети.

Answer (score 0):

Технология "Wake On Lan" (технология "Magic packet") используется для включения электропитания удаленного компьютера, находящегося в состоянии программного выключения ("Soft Off") путем посылки на его сетевой адаптер специально сформированного кадра Ethernet. 
То есть сетевая карта должна мерцать. 
Посмотрите в настройках сетевой карты доступен ли Wake on Magic Packet?

Comment: А как в этом случае работает по локальной сети?

Answer (score -1):

Предположу, что роутер может отключаться от интернета из-за того, что к нему нет обращений в течение заданного периода времени. Стоит попробовать изменить эту настройку.

Comment: там нет такой настройки. и роутер не отключается.